# Crush builded React Native Expo app on Android

Tags: android, react-native, debugging, expo

I have a component that toggle on click, it works fine with expo go, but after running the Android application build, it gives the following error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray.size()' on a null object reference

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT9D2.jpg)

```
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <>
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => {
          if (!!props.category?.children) setOpen((prevState) => !prevState);
          else {
            // @ts-ignore
            navigation.navigate({
              name: "Category",
              params: { category: props.category },
              key: "Category-" + props.category.id,
            });
          }
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.categoryItem}>
          <View style={styles.rightView}>
            <View style={styles.imageBox}>
              <Image
                style={styles.image}
                source={{ uri: props.category.image }}
              />
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{props.category.name}</Text>
          </View>
          {!!props.category.children && (
            <Svg
              style={[
                styles.arrow,
                open && { transform: [{ rotate: "90deg" }] },
              ]}
              width="20"
              height="20"
              viewBox="0 0 28 28"
              fill="none"
            >
              <Path
                d="M20.1523 14.1445C20.1523 14.4521 20.0381 14.7158 19.792 14.9443L12.9541 21.6416C12.7607 21.835 12.5146 21.9404 12.2246 21.9404C11.6445 21.9404 11.1787 21.4834 11.1787 20.8945C11.1787 20.6045 11.3018 20.3496 11.4951 20.1475L17.6562 14.1445L11.4951 8.1416C11.3018 7.93945 11.1787 7.67578 11.1787 7.39453C11.1787 6.80566 11.6445 6.34863 12.2246 6.34863C12.5146 6.34863 12.7607 6.4541 12.9541 6.64746L19.792 13.3359C20.0381 13.5732 20.1523 13.8369 20.1523 14.1445Z"
                fill="rgba(117, 117, 117, 0.5)"
              />
            </Svg>
          )}
        </View>
      </Pressable>
      <View style={[styles.children, !open && { display: "none" }]}>
        {props.category.children?.map((child) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              // @ts-ignore
              navigation.navigate({
                name: "Category",
                params: { category: child },
                key: "Category-" + child.id,
              });
            }}
            key={child.id}
            style={styles.child}
          >
            <Text style={styles.childTitle}>{child.name}</Text>
            <View style={styles.underLine}></View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the mistake was.
The problem was that this element does not work correctly with transform.
So I changed the code this way:

```
<View
    style={[
            styles.arrow,
            open && { transform: [{ rotate: "90deg" }] },
          ]}
        >
          <Svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 28 28" fill="none">
            <Path
              d="M20.1523 14.1445C20.1523 14.4521 20.0381 14.7158 19.792 14.9443L12.9541 21.6416C12.7607 21.835 12.5146 21.9404 12.2246 21.9404C11.6445 21.9404 11.1787 21.4834 11.1787 20.8945C11.1787 20.6045 11.3018 20.3496 11.4951 20.1475L17.6562 14.1445L11.4951 8.1416C11.3018 7.93945 11.1787 7.67578 11.1787 7.39453C11.1787 6.80566 11.6445 6.34863 12.2246 6.34863C12.5146 6.34863 12.7607 6.4541 12.9541 6.64746L19.792 13.3359C20.0381 13.5732 20.1523 13.8369 20.1523 14.1445Z"
              fill="rgba(117, 117, 117, 0.5)"
            />
          </Svg>
 </View>
```